# paper js drawing (item/path) hierarchy

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am developing a JavaScript based animation app using Paper JS.

In their sample here: http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/ when you click on an object, it jumps to the front.

Now, what I want is when you click on an object it stays on it's hierarchy (like z-index) just like any illustration app (last drawn object always on top of the previous drawn one).

Been searching for options to solve the issue but no luck.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just comment out lines 72 and 73:

```
if (movePath)
    project.activeLayer.addChild(hitResult.item);
```

Those lines make the item go at the top of the active layer (the item is removed and re-added to the layer).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I see the .addChild operation is the one causing it.